# R como fazer o calculo em diferentes linhas do data.frame

Tags: r, data.frame

Eu estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
temp <- data.frame(ano = c(1997,1999,2001,2003,2005,2007,2009,2013,2019))

a <- (temp[2,1]-temp[1,1])+1

b <- (temp[3,1]-temp[1,1])+1

c <- (temp[4,1]-temp[1,1])+1

d <- (temp[5,1]-temp[1,1])+1

f <- (temp[6,1]-temp[1,1])+1

g <- (temp[7,1]-temp[1,1])+1

h <- (temp[8,1]-temp[1,1])+1

i <- (temp[9,1]-temp[1,1])+1

temp["t"] <- c(1,a,b,c,d,f,g,h,i)
```

Chego no seguinte resultado:

```
ano   t
1997  1
1999  3
2001  5
2003  7
2005  9
2007  11
2009  13
2013  17
2019  23
```

Como eu faço para otimizar esse processo, sem ter que sempre declarar as variáveis? Existe alguma forma de fazer esses cálculos direto no `data.frame` de um jeito que a primeira linha seja sempre `t=1` e as demais seguindo a formula na coluna `t` do `data.frame`:

```
linha2=(ano2-ano1)+1 
linha3=(ano3-ano1)+1
```

e assim por diante.

Tem como esse processo ser automático? Sem declarações de variáveis da coluna `t`, declarando apenas os anos da primeira coluna, para que possa ser usada em outras entradas na coluna `ano`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `R` é uma linguagem que permite você fazer cálculos vetorizados, então basta:

```
temp$t <- (temp$ano - 1997) +1
```

para que a conta seja aplicada  a todas as linhas do seu `data.frame`.